# Ignoring an ignore pattern with svn:global-ignores property

Tags: svn, ignore

What I'm trying to do is ignore a pattern in the whole project, except in some rare subdirectories. It's inconvenient to add a pattern to every directory, especially because it should be done every time a new one directory is added to repo. The svn:global-ignores property (not to be confused with global-ignores configuration setting!!!) would do the work, except that it's inherited to all child directories. The question is: is there a legitimate way to ignore an ignore pattern? For example,

```
foo/ : svn:global-ignores *.js
foo/bar/ : svn:global-ignores ~*
```

ignores both ~* and *.js in foo/bar/, and I want not to ignore *.js under foo/bar/.

I tried !*.js for foo/bar/ and magically it seems to work, but it's not documented and I just might be wrong. Does it really work?